# Disabling direct IP access Using .htaccess

Tags: windows, apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I have a website which is placed behind a reverse proxy..I want to use .htaccess file to do the follwing:

Incase of direct access to any of the web directory files (IP access instead of domain),he gets a genuine 404 not found error,not a made-up one..

Also,if possible,I'd like to whitelist certain IPs,so they can freely browse the website through direct IP connection(without the need of domain).

p.s. I'm using Apache on Windows.

I searched and found something like that :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domainname\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) -  [F]
```

It didn't work as expected.

Thanks..

Comment: If you just redirect, what is the main purpose of requiring the "correct" host name from the request?

Comment: I don't want it to be redirected,I want it to show as offline/not available.

Answer (score 0):

You could add your main configuration as a named virtual host which only listen on the specified domain. If you do this your "default" Apache configuration could be used to always give a 404 page.

This would give the result you'd expect - but require control over the entire Apache configuration and not just the htaccess-file.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first `RewriteCond` directive and try again. `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .` will make your RewriteRule fire only when there is at least one character in the host name, which is exactly not what you want.